# Find Where a Parametric Equation Overlaps

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a parametric equation:

```
r[t_] = {2.9 Cos[3.2 Pi t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 5 t};
```

which overlaps at a point in the $\{-x, y\}$ region of a plot.

I'm trying to figure the simplest way of finding the $\{x, y\}$ coordinates of the point of overlap, but I'm  not having any luck.  I do know that the point of overlap is between `0.1 < t < 0.2` and `0.4 < t < 0.5`.

```
curve = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
point = Graphics[{Red, Disk[r[0.175], .075]}];
Show[curve, point]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by _overlap_?

Comment: Basically, there's a point where the r[t] crosses over itself (around t=.33) and I'm trying to find the x,y coordinates where that happens

Comment: So, the `t`s where the plot "comes back", e.g. $(x,y)=(-2.9,0.9)$?

Comment: I'm looking for the point where they cross over, which is near (x,y) = (-0.6 , 1.7)

Comment: Woops! The point I'm looking for is closer to (t=.175), sorry for the confusion

Comment: Related: [(33947)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Almost identical to [(94498)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94498), which is itself a duplicate of [(33947)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33947).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `FindRoot` with started values determined from OP's `Show[curve, point]`:

```
r[t_] = {2.9 Cos[3.2 Pi t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 5 t};

sol = FindRoot[r[t2] - r[t1], {{t1, 0.175}, {t2, 0.45}}]
(* {t1 -> 0.173318, t2 -> 0.451682} *)

{r[t1], r[t2]} /. sol
(* {{-0.495174, 1.68785}, {-0.495174, 1.68785}} *)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help! I wasn't even looking at the FindRoot function

Answer (score 5):

This question also can be addressed by eliminating `t`.

```
g = y /. Simplify[Solve[{x == 29/10 Cos[32/10 Pi t], y == Sin[4 Pi t] + 5 t}, {y, t}], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers] // Expand /. C[1] -> c

(* {-25*ArcCos[10*x/29]/(16*Pi) + 25*C[1]/8 + Sin[(5*(-ArcCos[10*x/29] + 2*Pi*C[1]))/4], 
     25*ArcCos[10*x/29]/(16*Pi) + 25*C[1]/8 + Sin[(5*( ArcCos[10*x/29] + 2*Pi*C[1]))/4]} *)
```

This expression can be plotted as

```
f = Reverse@g; f[[2]] = f[[2]] /. c -> c + 1;
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f, {c, 0, 3}]], {x, -29/10, 29/10}]
```

[image]

`y` is periodic with a period of `g[[1]] /. c -> 4 /. ArcCos[(10 x)/29] -> 0`, which is `25/2`.  The three crossing points are given by

```
With[{d = 0}, {x, f[[1]] /. c -> d} /. FindRoot[Equal @@ f /. c -> d, {x, 0}]]
(* {-0.495174, 1.68785} *)
With[{d = 2}, {x, g[[1]] /. c -> d} /. FindRoot[Equal @@ g /. c -> d, {x, 0}]]
(* {-0.38559, 6.25} *)
With[{d = 3}, {x, f[[1]] /. c -> d} /. FindRoot[Equal @@ f /. c -> d, {x, 0}]]
(* {-0.495174, 10.8122} *)
```

All other roots can be obtained, of course, by adding integer multiples of `12.5` to `y`.

Answer (score 4):

Or use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) with exact equations

```
r[t_] = Hold[{2.9 Cos[3.2 Pi t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 5 t}] /. 
    z_?NumberQ :> Rationalize[z] // ReleaseHold;

soln = NSolve[
   {r[t1] == r[t2], 1/10 < t1 < 2/10, 4/10 < t2 < 5/10},
   {t1, t2}][[1]]

(*  {t1 -> 0.173318, t2 -> 0.451682}  *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
r[t1] == r[t2] /. soln

(*  True  *)
```

The intersection point is

```
pt = r[t1] /. soln

(*  {-0.495174, 1.68785}  *)

curve = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}];

point = Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[pt]}];

Show[curve, point]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: This is an exaggeration, but incorporates a number of techniques that might be applied to many other problems.*

---

Let's take

```
r[t_] = {2.9 Cos[3.2 Pi t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 5 t};
```

and the bounds for `t`

```
min = 0;
max = 3;
```

The first step is to extract the intersections from the plot:

```
curve = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, min, max}, Axes -> None, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

The pixel positions of the intersections can be extracted with

```
px = PixelValuePositions[#, White] & @
  MorphologicalBranchPoints @ Thinning @ Binarize @ curve
```

> {{74, 410}, {64, 407}, {64, 313}, {74, 311}, {71, 180}, {75, 
>     180}, {74, 50}, {64, 47}}

We need to connect them to the actual coordinates on the plot:

```
pl = PlotRange@curve
```

> {{-2.9, 2.9}, {0., 15.}}

```
id = ImageDimensions@curve
```

> {167, 432}

The relation between `pl` and `id` is linear, $y=ax+b$ and $y=cx+d$ in the horizontal and vertical directions, respecively:

```
{a, b} = {a, b} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[1, 1]] == b, pl[[1, 2]] == a id[[1]] + b}, {a, b}]
{c, d} = {c, d} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[2, 1]] == d, pl[[2, 2]] == c id[[2]] + d}, {c, d}]
```

> {0.0347305, -2.9}
>
> {0.0347222, 0.}

The pixel positions transformed to plot coordinates:

```
ic = {a #1 + b, c #2 + d} & @@@ px
```

> {{-0.32994, 14.2361}, {-0.677245, 14.1319}, {-0.677245, 
>     10.8681}, {-0.32994, 10.7986}, {-0.434132, 6.25}, {-0.29521, 
>     6.25}, {-0.32994, 1.73611}, {-0.677245, 1.63194}}

look like this:

[image]

Not exactly at the intersections, but this is good enough. We can get rid of the ambiguity with clustering:

```
clu = ClusterClassify@ic
```

> Method: DBSCAN
>
> Number of classes: 4

```
g = GatherBy[ic, clu]
```

> {{{-0.32994, 14.2361}, {-0.677245, 14.1319}}, {{-0.677245, 
>      10.8681}, {-0.32994, 10.7986}}, {{-0.434132, 6.25}, {-0.29521, 
>      6.25}}, {{-0.32994, 1.73611}, {-0.677245, 1.63194}}}

```
icmean = Reverse[Mean /@ g]
```

> {{-0.503593, 1.68403}, {-0.364671, 6.25}, {-0.503593, 
>     10.8333}, {-0.503593, 14.184}}

which works very well:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, min, max}, Axes -> None, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[#]}] &@icmean]
```

[image]

The above works perfectly, and I believe it answers a number of other questions here: [(41496)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/graphicsmeshfindintersections-fails-to-detect-intersections?noredirect=1&lq=1), [(78616)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78616/problems-finding-intersection-points-between-line-and-generic-function?rq=1), [(99529)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99529/finding-intersection-points-of-two-graphics?rq=1), [(126847)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126847/equation-solving-intersection-of-graphs/126852#126852).

Now, to find `t` for which the intersection occur, we need to do some careful solving:

```
ff1 = Flatten@
  Table[Select[min < # < max &][
    t /. Quiet@NSolve[r[t][[1]] == icmean[[i, 1]], t]], {i, 1, 
    Length@icmean}]
ff2 = Table[
  t /. NSolve[r[t][[2]] == icmean[[i, 2]], t, Reals], {i, 1, 
   Length@icmean}]
```

> {0.173612, 0.168792, 0.173612, 0.173612}
>
> {{0.140671, 0.174995, 0.451432}, {1.08048, 1.25, 1.41952}, {2.04971, 
>     2.31875, 2.36513}, {2.64067, 2.675, 2.95143}}

and create the set of starting points:

```
fr = Table[{ff2[[i, 1]], ff2[[i, -1]]}, {i, 1, Length@ff2}]
```

> {{0.140671, 0.451432}, {1.08048, 1.41952}, {2.04971, 
>     2.36513}, {2.64067, 2.95143}}

and now use [Xavier's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127165/22013)

```
final = {t1, t2} /. 
  Table[FindRoot[
    r[t2] - r[t1], {{t1, fr[[i, 1]]}, {t2, fr[[i, 2]]}}], {i, 1, 
    Length@fr}]
```

> {{0.173318, 0.451682}, {1.08048, 1.41952}, {2.04832, 
>     2.32668}, {2.67332, 2.95168}}

Each pair `{t1, t2}` should correspond to one intersection:

```
points = Table[
   Graphics[{Red, Disk[r[Flatten[final][[i]]], .1]}], {i, 1, 
    Length@Flatten[final]}];
```

[image]

All solutions have been found in an automated manner.